# d3.js. How to organize bubbles along the line without overlaps?

Tags: layout, d3.js

I want to make such kind of bubble chart:
[image]
But only i can do is here - http://jsfiddle.net/zeleniy/h646uopc/6/.

```
jsfiddle code mock
```

How i can move them apart to escape overlapping. I understand that in some cases bubbles will be shifted along the x axis because of chart height limit. But in any case i do not know how to do it? And i am not sure that want to use force layout to scatter bubbles. I want do draw it at once.

Comment: so in the fiddle you have an x axis and the circle are placed based on the x data rate...so if there are two data set points having same data rate they will overlap .. however the screen shot you have put does not have x or y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i do it - http://zeleniy.me/stretched-bubble-chart.html.
You should use force layout with specific gravity implementation. Read this article for details - http://vallandingham.me/building_a_bubble_cloud.html